# Setting an ElasticSearch geo_point Mapper Type via Elastical (node.js)

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I've been digging through the [Elastical](https://github.com/ramv/node-elastical) source trying to figure out how to set a Core Type when creating an index. Specifically, I need to set a field as a geo_point field.

In [Mongoosastic](http://jamescarr.github.com/mongoosastic/) I just set the es_type field on my schema, but I can't figure out how to do the equivalent in Elastical.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was looking for the "putMapping" function.

```
elastical.putMapping(index, type, {'type': {'properties': {"coords" : {"type" : "geo_point", "store": "yes"}}}}, function(e,r){});
```